# Не получается перегрузить оператор присваивания в шаблонном классе

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, перегрузка-операторов

Нужно перегрузить оператор присваивания в шаблонном классе, не могу понять, почему не работает стандартный синтаксис, при реализации выдает эту ошибку (/home/anton/Programming/tree/tree.h:96: ошибка: overloaded 'operator=' must be a binary operator (has 1 parameter)). Объявление и реализация в одном .h файле.

Объявление:

```
 tree<T>& operator = (tree<T> &other);
```

реалицация:

```
template <class T>
tree<T>& operator = (tree<T> &other)
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну надо указать, какому классу он принадлежит... А так вы пытались реализовать унарный оператор `=`...

```
template <class T>
tree<T>& tree<T>::operator = (tree<T> &other)
{
}
```

И еще - вы точно планируете при присваивании менять присваиваемое? Может, лучше

```
template <class T>
tree<T>& tree<T>::operator = (const tree<T> &other)
{
}
```

Comment: оператор не обязательно  должен принадлежать классу

Comment: проблема в том, что когда присваиваемый объект константный, нельзя вызвать его мтеод, даже если в самом объекте он ничего не меняет

Comment: Какой метод? Вас послушать - константность вообще невозможна :) Может, вы не так меня понимаете? Под присваиваемым я имею в виду (и это совершенно очевидно из кода) тот объект, который присваивается другому, который находится справа.